# VS2013 deployment is stopping when last project is built

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my project in using Visual Studio 2013 to Azure. It goes through the building process but once the last project is built, it does not continue anymore. It just runs in there and doesn't want to continue to deployment no matter how long I leave it.

I did a diagnostic output for the build but the last line just says:

```
Target "Build" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Done building project
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a project to Azure you use Publish, not Build. You can find Publish in the Build-menu as well. Hope this helps!